# Does Glee use excessive auto tune?

Tags: production, glee

I know most pop music uses some auto tune, but I've heard a few Glee songs (against my will) and the auto tune seemed almost omnipresent! Does Glee use auto tune more than typical pop music normally does?

Answer (score 4):

The question itself is rather subjective as the 'pop music' genre in general is quite broad, and I don't think anyone could define what a typical pop song was.

Considering that Glee is primarily a TV show, with time and cost restraints. I would have assumed the actors wont have the same amount of time to get the vocals 'just perfect', in the same way a professional recording artist would (recording artist often layer vocal track after vocal track) and so autotune is a way to speed up this process.

That being said; in an interview with [Hollywood Reporter](http://www.hollywoodreporter.com/news/glee-music-98277%20Here), Glee's music producer, Adam Anders is adamant that autotune is only used to create an accurate cover of the original track

> We don't use auto-tune. It's complete BS. Do I edit the vocals? Of course...
>   When things are autotuned, it's on purpose -- to match the original song, like Lady Gaga’s "Telephone,"

So to answer the question, autotune isn't used as much as you may think, and is definately not used any more than a 'typical' pop song.

Comment: So, the "official" answer is that they don't use it that much. They're not admitting to over-using it, huh. ;)

Comment: I have to tell you I was surprised!

Comment: Sorry you were forced to watch Glee BTW :(